# Scala method won't compile

Tags: list, scala, methods

I am trying to create a recursive method that will remove 0's from a list and return that list.

```
def removeZero(lst: List[Int], num: Int) = lst match {
  case h :: tail => if (h == num)
      tail
    else 
      h :: removeZero(lst, num)
  case List() => List()
}
```

However this won't compile. I get a StackOverflow error. I am trying to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: What is the error you get? Recursive methods require an explicit return type so try adding one first.

Comment: like "case Nil => 0"

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense to me. Edit your post to include the error you are getting, too.

Comment: OK, that was a bizarre edit. Your method is called `removeZero,` you don't want to be comparing `h` to it!

Comment: That was a typo. (h==removeZero) was meant...but I still get an error. Stack overflow

Comment: The stack overflow is caused by: `removeZero(lst, num)`, it should be: `removeZero(tail, num)` since in the recursive call you're not reducing the `lst` argument.

Comment: Yes! that works @irundaia. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
def removeZero(lst: List[Int], num: Int): List[Int] = lst match {
  case h :: tail => if (h == num)
      tail
    else
      h :: removeZero(tail, num)
  case List() => List()
}
```

Your condition in the non-empty case should compare the head with `num` instead of the method `removeZero`. In the `else` branch you should recurse through the list by passing the tail into the recursive call instead of the entire list.